# How to use java Map<String, Object> where scala Map[String, Any] is requred?

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

How to use/convert Map to scala Map[String, Any]?

Java Object is recognized as AnyRef in scala.

Is there any one line conversion available? I would like to avoid iterating over newly created scala Map and copying refs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this:

```
  val jmap = new HashMap[String, Object]
  jmap.put("1", new Date)

  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val smap = jmap.asScala.mapValues(_.asInstanceOf[Any]).toMap
  test(smap)

  def test(m: Map[String, Any]): Unit = {
    println(m)
  }
```

Also be aware that `java.lang.Object` is equivalent to `AnyRef` in Scala, not `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val javaMap = new HashMap[String,Object]
val scalaMap: Map[String,Any] = javaMap.toMap
```

Or, if you don't like "the magic of implicits", do this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ // note, this is a different import
val javaMap = new HashMap[String, Object]
val scalaMap: Map[String, Any] = javaMap.asScala.toMap // this .asScala is what the other version does implicitly
```

Note also, that the `toMap` in the end is needed because `javaMap.asScala` returns a `mutable.Map`, and the `Map[String,Any]` declaration defaults to an `immutable.Map` by default. 
If you use `scala.collection.Map` instead, you won't need it:

```
import scala.collection.Map
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val javaMap = HashMap[String, Object]
val scalaMap: Map[String,Any] = javaMap // voila!
```

or explicitly

```
import scala.collection.Map
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val javaMap = HashMap[String, Object]
val scalaMap: Map[String, Any] = javaMap.asScala
```